# Permanenly remove url from google SERP

Tags: seo, search-results

How to permanently remove the search result which I deleted from the website? I previously added those url in google webmaster sitemaps.

Is there any way to hide those url permanently from google SERP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since this is a duplicate question you can try the methods stated at the original question. I also found one more Google webmasters document to [Block access to your content](https://support.google.com/webmasters/topic/4598466). Maybe this will also be useful to you.